# How to use find.byType matching of List in Flutter widget testing

Tags: testing, flutter, widget

I want to do widget testing for a Stack. Here is the sample code

```dart
final List<Widget> children = [];
final stack = Stack(children: children);
await tester.pumpWidget(Container(child: stack));
...

final stackFinder = find.byWidget(stack);
expect(stackFinder, findsOneWidget);

// children should be in Stack
final childrenFinder = find.descendant(
  of: stackFinder,
  matching: find.byType(children.runtimeType),
);
expect(childrenFinder, findsWidgets);
```

but get error:

```
Expected: at least one matching node in the widget tree
  Actual: ?:<zero widgets with type "List<Widget>" that has ancestor(s) with type "Stack"
```

I try to change matching to `matching: find.byType([].runtimeType),` or `matching: find.byType(List<Widget>),` but it doesn't work too.

Do you know how to fix it? Or, in case it's impossible, which method you use to verify the number of children inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<Widgets>` is not a widget. Therefore you cannot create a finder that will look for that type.

You could instead look for `Widget` and check if you find the correct number of widget that you are expecting.